# Generate a collection containing only maximum values in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, geemap

I'm fairly new to GEE and I'm trying to modify a collection of ECMWF ERA5 in order to create an mean image of the maximum values from a period of time. I've tried `.map` function but nothing displays on a screen. My code looked something like this:

```
var Poland= ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co','PL'));
var startdate19 = '2019-03-16';
var enddate19 = '2019-04-20';
var startdate20 = '2020-03-16';
var enddate20 = '2020-04-20';

var temperature = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_RAW")
                  .select('temperature_2m')
                  .map(function(image){return image.max(image)})
                  .map(function(image){return image.clip(Poland)});
var temp2019 = temperatura.filter(ee.Filter.date(startdate19, enddate19)).mean();
var temp2020 = temperatura.filter(ee.Filter.date(startdate20, enddate20)).mean();
var paletaTemp =  {
  min: 275,
  max: 287,
  palette: ['0066ff','00fff3','00ff14','fbff00','ffc800','ff0c00','d20000']
};
Map.addLayer(temp2019, paletaTemp, 'temp19')
Map.addLayer(temp2020, paletaTemp, 'temp20')
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0b50683c59f74e3675b19af2b2f7a91c

```js
var Poland= ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co','PL'));
var startdate19 = '2019-03-16';
var enddate19 = '2019-04-20';
var startdate20 = '2020-03-16';
var enddate20 = '2020-04-20';

// Consider the following image.max(image) test: 
var foo = ee.Image(0).set({"system:time_start":ee.Date("2019-01-01")})
print(foo)  // Has a system:time_start property
var bar = foo.max(foo);
print(bar) // Same as foo, but no system:time_start property
// image.max(image) is useless and removes the ability 
// to apply an ee.Filter.date in an image collection.

var temperature = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_RAW")
                  .select('temperature_2m')
                  //.map(function(image){return image.max(image)}) // This is useless.
                  .map(function(image){return image.clip(Poland)});
                
var temp2019 = temperature.filter(ee.Filter.date(startdate19, enddate19)).max();
// temp2019 is now an ee.Image where each pixel in Poland corresponds to the maximum value
// within the startdate19 to enddate19 period. 

// Now that you have the maximum value.. how do you want the mean?
// do you want the spatial mean? 
// then you want to use ee.Image.reduceRegion (or reduceRegions)
// and you will get either a dictionary or a featureCollection. 

print(temp2019)

var paletaTemp =  {
  min: 275,
  max: 287,
  palette: ['0066ff','00fff3','00ff14','fbff00','ffc800','ff0c00','d20000']
};
Map.addLayer(temp2019, paletaTemp, 'temp19')
```

Note that the first function that you mapped is not doing what you think it's doing -- in fact, it is removing the ability for you to filter the collection because it removes the properties from the image (including `system:time_start`).

The code above demonstrates this, and then gives you an image containing the maximum values over the selected 2019 period. How do you want to compute the mean next? the only option is to get a spatial mean, because now you have an image, not an image collection.